# using global exception handeling messes up DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, .net-4.5.2, webapi2

When ovveride the IExceptionHandler, the response does not reach the DelegatingHandler when a unexpected exception occurs. How can I fix this?

In webapi 2, I want to implement a audit logger for request and response messages. I also want to add a global exception handler. However, when I replace the IExceptionHandler with my custom implementation. the response never reaches the DelegatingHandler -on exception - And thus the audit for response is lost.

in WebApiConfig

```
// add custom audittrail logger
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuditLogHandler());
// replace global exception handeling
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new WebAPiExceptionHandler());
```

Custom Exception Handler

```
public class WebAPiExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    //A basic DTO to return back to the caller with data about the error
    private class ErrorInformation
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }
    }

    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
        new ErrorInformation { Message = "Iets is misgegaan", ErrorDate = DateTime.UtcNow }));
    }
}
```

Custom Auditlogger

```
public class AuditLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            var task = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // .. code for loggign request
        }

        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // .. code for logging response
        // when I do not replace WebAPiExceptionHandler, code is reachred here
        // When I Do use WebAPiExceptionHandler, code is not reached here

        return result;
    }
}
```

Code for throwing exception in webapi

```
public class Values_v2Controller : ApiController
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        throw new Exception("haha");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use ExceptionHandler as base class, implement interface IExceptionHandler

```
public class WebAPiExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fout = new ErrorInformation
        {
            Message = "Iets is misgegaan"
            , ErrorDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        var httpResponse = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, fout);

        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(httpResponse);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private class ErrorInformation
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ExceptionHandler` only executes `Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)` method if `ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)` returns true.

Overriding `bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)` to always return true fix the problem for me.

Comment: @Liam You're right. Thanks. I edited the answer to fix it.